# How to update a UILabel's text based on a instance's property

Tags: ios, swift, class, sprite-kit, uilabel

I'm attempting to update my "Lives Remaining: " `UILabel`, and I'm having trouble getting it to update based on a class's or instances current variable value- in this case `lives`. I'm using `didSet` to do so in my following code:

The `Ship` class:

```
class Ship:SKSpriteNode{

    ...

    var lives:Int = 0{
        didSet{
            shipLivesLabel?.text = self.lives.description

        }
    }
```

Instantiating the label in `GameScene`:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    private var shipLives = 0 {
        didSet{
            self.shipLivesLabel?.text = aShip.lives.description
        }
    }
    private var shipLivesLabel:SKLabelNode?
```

and where I'm adding it to the scene:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let shipLivesLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Times New Roman")
    shipLivesLabel.text = shipLives.description
    shipLivesLabel.fontSize = 14
    shipLivesLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*1.3,y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*0.1)
    self.addChild(shipLivesLabel)
    self.shipLivesLabel = shipLivesLabel
```

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to go about this, and I'm also not sure how to reference the `shipLivesLabel` within the `Ship` class- I receive the error: `Instance member shipLivesLabel cannot be used on type GameScene`. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Not entirely sure that you should be using `description` in this way

Comment: @tibrogargan Could you elaborate? And any idea how I could reference the text property of the label from within my class like this?

Comment: I believe `description` is primarily used for debugging.  However, the method says `A string that represents the contents of the receiving class` .. and you're doing that, so it's perhaps a valid use (may make debugging more interesting).  As for your error, no idea (or I'd have posted an answer).  There are a lot of SO questions that mention the same error (google `Instance member cannot be used on type`) - I'd start reading

Comment: You can't set the label from the ship node, it doesn't know anything about the label.  Your game scene should update the lives. The ship is just an object in the scene. It shouldn't know anything about "lives".

Comment: @paulw11 The ship is supposed to have a `lives` property that is decremented when it's hit. I just wanted to display this information to the user? Any idea how I could go about this differently?

Comment: Those sort of game mechanics should be managed in your game scene.  You can store a lives property on your ship, but it isn't the ship's job to update the lives label.  When you detect a collision and decrement lives on the ship in your game scene then you should also update your lives label

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in :

```
private var shipLives = 0 {
        didSet{
            self.shipLivesLabel?.text = aShip.lives.description
        }
}
```

where your `self.shipLivesLabel` could be not ready during this assignment.

### **So what happened?**

You try to assign to a not initialized class, a value to his property.

**Bad syntax**:

```
MyClass.variable = 'Foo' 
// error:  Instance member 'variable' cannot be used on type 'MyClass'
```

**Good syntax**:

```
instanceOfMyClass.variable = 'Foo'
```

About your case:

`GameScene.shipLivesLabel` assignment used before `GameScene` is fully initialized.

I don't like your approach to write important game properties like the lives counter of your characters. Please take a look to this answer to better understand what I mean: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38671139/1894067)

---

Another advice gived by Tibrogargan in question comments is to don't use description: it's a bad attitude, it's used for debugging, live is an `Int` and if you want to assign this one to a `String` do:

```
shipLivesLabel.text = "\(shipLives)"
```